# Display two different images from JSON

Tags: android, json, android-glide

Recycler adapter

```
package com.example.maztec.celebstars.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.maztec.celebstars.Pojodata.HeaderData;
import com.example.maztec.celebstars.Pojodata.ItemResponse2;
import com.example.maztec.celebstars.Pojodata.actorsrcs;
import com.example.maztec.celebstars.R;

import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.List;

public class ImageRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageRecyclerAdapter.GetHeadersrcs> {
    private Context context;
    private List<HeaderData> Hsrcs;

    public ImageRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<HeaderData> hsrcs) {
        this.context = context;
        Hsrcs = hsrcs;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageRecyclerAdapter.GetHeadersrcs onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_header_design,parent,false);
        return new GetHeadersrcs(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageRecyclerAdapter.GetHeadersrcs holder, int position) {
        HeaderData hdata=Hsrcs.get(position);
        final String id=hdata.getId();
        Glide.with(context).load(hdata.getCat_image()).error(R.drawable.defaultceleb).into(holder.Headerimg1);
        Glide.with(context).load(hdata.getCat_image()).error(R.drawable.defaultceleb).into(holder.Headerimg2);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Hsrcs.size();
    }

    public class GetHeadersrcs extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView Headerimg1;
        ImageView Headerimg2;

        public GetHeadersrcs(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Headerimg1=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circ1);
            Headerimg2=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.circ2);
        }
    }

    public  void setHeaderdata(List<HeaderData> headerdata){
        this.Hsrcs=headerdata;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

[image]

and here's the JSON response

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "cat_name":"Actor",
         "cat_image":"http://mapi.trycatchtech.com/uploads/bollywood_wallpaper/1d96964ff5fee52c459b430399d0ad6b.jpg"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "cat_name":"Actress",
         "cat_image":"http://mapi.trycatchtech.com/uploads/bollywood_wallpaper/7b9d2f40a3f0fe3b6b37e66b5992be3a.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "last_update":"1525853619"
}
```

What I want is one view for actor and one view for Actress, if you can guide me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to tell where the issue is if you don't explain what you have tried out.

I would guess it is a logic error with one of you methods. Maybe check the **hdata.getCat_image()** and see if that is returning what you expect

Comment: i'm trying to display two images in my layout from the api link, where in the layout there is 2 image views with seperate imagesviews ids.now the cat_image() method shd display both the images but its only displaying  the 1 image in both the image views as shows in the Output pic

Comment: Are you sure its not loading R.drawable.defaultceleb in both because both may be erroring?

Comment: no its not, the default image if there's any server issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have only one image per row of the view. So change:

```
HeaderData hdata=Hsrcs.get(position);
final String id=hdata.getId();
Glide.with(context).load(hdata.getCat_image()).error(R.drawable.defaultceleb).into(holder.Headerimg1);
Glide.with(context).load(hdata.getCat_image()).error(R.drawable.defaultceleb).into(holder.Headerimg2);
```

to:

```
HeaderData hdata=Hsrcs.get(position);
final String id=hdata.getId();
Glide.with(context).load(hdata.getCat_image()).error(R.drawable.defaultceleb).into(holder.Headerimg1);
```

You can remove `Headerimg2` as using only `Headerimg1` will suffice.

Comment: it didn't work as im using two image views for diff images actor and actress so using just one will only display 1 image

Comment: @Mazhar thats fine but your json has only one image item per object, if you want to show the two images in one row then you have to change the way you pass the json data to the recycler adapter

Comment: how do u suggest i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are calling the same method that is retrieving the same image from the JSON data for both ImageViews

```
hdata.getCat_image()
```

Comment: the 'hdata.getCat_image()' is just a pojo data the question is how to get the 2 image from the api

Comment: Replace the first hdata.getCat_image() with a method that retreives cat_image: ... from the obj in the first position of the JSON array, And the same with the second

Comment: https://github.com/maztrek/CelebStars this is my github link can you show me how to do that im new to android development